# Development, hosting and administration HTML5 games and shopping system

Tags: html, gambling

I am working for a start-up company that is building a platform of HTML5 gambling games. I was asked to suggest the server technology and hosting solution that should be used. The games need to be able to communicate, allowing among other things for a system of credits that will allow shopping within the site. What do you recommend? Please list all technologies/frameworks/etc you recommend as an integrated solution for such a platform of games - playable on any device.
Also please recommend books that could be helpful with development, hosting and administration of it all.

Answer (score 0):

Lets breakdown your question into simpler parts. Many technologies can help in each of these parts. I will list the most popular open source ones.

1. **Ruby on Rails:** For fast development and deploying of scalable web apps.
2. **Database:** Many options available depending on RDBMS approach or NoSQL approach. Production level performance examples include sqlite, mongoDB etc.
3. **Twitter Bootstrap:** For the best front-end GUI experience on multiple devices.
4. **CMS :** Joomla, Drupal for getting a quick start. Not recommended for very fast scalability.
5. **Infrastructure:** No one beats Amazon in prices! You have many solutions to choose from and also pay only for the infrastructure that you use.

In addition, follow the development blogs of hugely successful gaming corporations (Rovio, Zynga etc.) to get more details of the stacks they use.

If you can tell me details of technologies that are already used in your start-up, I can zoom in on solutions which will be faster for your developers to switch to.